# How to setup Subfolders for multiple Store Views?

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

Before asking this question, I did Google search but could not find a clear answer.

**I have:**

- 01 Website + 01 Store
- 03 Store Views (vi, en, zh) sharing same products and categories

**I want to setup:**

- mydomain.com/vi (for Vietnamese)
- mydomain.com/en (for English)
- mydomain.com/zh (for Chinese)

(All the URLs above include "http://", StackExchange wants me to remove it away from the post)

**I did:** go to **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **General** -> **Web** -> choose **Store View** (vi, en, zh) -> edit **Base URL** for each Store View to be domain.com/vi (or zh, en) -> **Save Config** -> go to **Cache Management** -> **select all rows and Refresh**

**THE RESULT:** when going to the store home page (mydomain.com), the system redirects to the default Store View (which is mydomain.com/en), and then it shows 404 error.

**What am I missing? Please give me a clear step-by-step answer.** I'm using Apache with cPanel, PHP 7, Magento 2.1.2 Community Edition. I'm completely new to (2 days), I understand some basic fundamental ideas of Magento.

Your answers not only help me, but those newbies who would Google the same issue in the future.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

On *Magento 2.1.5* :

*Stores > Configuration > Web > Url Options*,
with selected Store view : "Default Config"

switch option "**Add Store Code to Urls**" to "**Yes**" :

you don't need to change base urls

Comment: Do you happen to know why the option `Add Store Code to Urls` select option  is not present for websites or stores view?. This seems to be available only `Default Config`.

Comment: I suppose it is only displayed on the `Default config` to not confuse users.